# how do I filter using dplyr for list of character strings ignoring numbers after a decimal place

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following column in a data.frame called "id":

```
   example_0test0|EMM3.71|NTERM| 
   example_0test1|_EMM92.2|CTERM| 
   example_0test2|_EMM92.2|NTERM| 
   example_0test0|EMM1|NTERM| 
   example_0test0|EMM100|NTERM| 
   example_0test0|EMM1.11|NTERM| 
   example_0test0|EMM1.123|NTERM|
```

I would like to filter using dplyr filter function for a list of exact characters such as (keeping it simple): `EMM1` to give the following output:

```
> test_df2
                              id col1 col2
1     example_0test0|EMM1|NTERM| 10.4 exp4
2  example_0test0|EMM1.11|NTERM| 10.3 exp6
3 example_0test0|EMM1.123|NTERM| 10.3 exp7
```

I have a factor list of characters saved like this I would like to use as input for the filtering terms:

```
"EMM1|EMM101|EMM103|EMM104|EMM108.1|EMM11|EMM113|EMM114|EMM116.1|EMM118|EMM12|EMM123|EMM19.4|EMM197|EMM2|"
```

I have tried using a combination using "filter" and "str_detect" which kind of worked HOWEVER if my search list includes "EMM1" I would like to include things like "EMM1.0" or "EMM1.1"

I suspect as each of my EMM terms in the column to filter by is encased in "|" like "`text|EMM1.0|text`" there might be a way to use this for the filtering?

here is a mini example of the type of data.frame I am working with:

```
> dput(test_df)
structure(list(id = c("example_0test0|EMM3.71|NTERM|", "example_0test1|_EMM92.2|CTERM|", 
"example_0test2|_EMM92.2|NTERM|", "example_0test0|EMM1|NTERM|", 
"example_0test0|EMM100|NTERM|", "example_0test0|EMM1.11|NTERM|", 
"example_0test0|EMM1.123|NTERM|"), col1 = c(10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 
10.4, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3), col2 = c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3", "exp4", 
"exp5", "exp6", "exp7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: have edited the post. Bearing in mind the expected output above is filtering for one term "EMM1" to give back all containing things like "EMM1","EMM1.11" etc but in reality I have hundreds of these to filter as in the factor list in the question... Thanks

Comment: My solution below is giving the expected output you showed

Comment: I updated the solution.  May be that helps

Comment: `subset(test_df, grepl(pat, id))` doesn't work? where `pat` is `pat <- "EMM1|EMM101|EMM103|EMM104|EMM108.1|EMM11|EMM113|EMM114|EMM116.1|EMM118|EMM12|EMM123|EMM19.4|EMM197|EMM2"` ?

Comment: @RonakShah this gives everything starting with EMM1, like emm106.9 EMM109.0 etc etc but this is the kind of thing I am after

Comment: I added an answer below taking that into consideration. You can check if it works on your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
pat <- "EMM1|EMM101|EMM103|EMM104|EMM108.1|EMM11|EMM113|EMM114|EMM116.1|EMM118|EMM12|EMM123|EMM19.4|EMM197|EMM2"
subset(test_df, grepl(sprintf('(%s)(\\.|\\|)', pat), id))


#                              id col1 col2
#4     example_0test0|EMM1|NTERM| 10.4 exp4
#6  example_0test0|EMM1.11|NTERM| 10.3 exp6
#7 example_0test0|EMM1.123|NTERM| 10.3 exp7
```

`pat` consists of all the `"EMM"` values that we want additionally we create a pattern using `sprintf` returning only those values which has a `"."` or `"|"` after those `pat` values.

---

We can also use this with `filter` and `str_detect` similarly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test_df %>% filter(str_detect(id, sprintf('(%s)(\\.|\\|)', pat)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test_df %>% 
    filter(str_detect(id, "EMM1\\||(EMM1\\.\\d+)"))
#                              id col1 col2
#1     example_0test0|EMM1|NTERM| 10.4 exp4
#2  example_0test0|EMM1.11|NTERM| 10.3 exp6
#3 example_0test0|EMM1.123|NTERM| 10.3 exp7
```

If we are filtering based on a column from another table, we could remove the `.` and the digits that follow

```
patvec <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", df2$id)
i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(paste0(patvec, "\\||(", patvec, "\\.\\d+)"),
      function(pat),
         grepl(pat, test_df$id)))
subset(test_df, i1)
```

Comment: This looks like the expected output for the simple example in the question, but I would like to filter for hundreds of similar terms, so typing them all out like "EMM1\\||" etc is not going to work. Thanks

Comment: @reubenmcg in your pattern list, it is also showed `EMM100`, so, it is not clear to me when the description says not to match "EMM100"

Comment: I have removed that art of the question, I cans see how it is confusing. Sorry

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I have now also removed the EMM100 form the string. So even if you use the example string in the question to filter the example data.frame I would still like to get back the same expected output table in the question.

Comment: Hmmm I see how that would help If I did not already have the string. But lets say I wanted to use the string provided, to filter the data.table provided. So using the fist parr of your answer but I do not want to type out all of the individual EMM's with \\|| etc

Comment: @reubenmcg in your post, it says that you are using some column from a different dataset? `have a factor list of characters saved like this from a column of another table`

Comment: I have removed the part specifically relating to another dataset, it was irrelevant to the output I am looking for...

Comment: @reubenmcg How are you getting that pattern vector.  Is it a vector initially and then you pasted together?  If that is the case, you can use the second solution in my post

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use base R approach

```
 df[grepl("EMM1(\\.\\d{1,})|EMM1\\|", df$id),]
 #                          id col1 col2
 # 4     example_0test0|EMM1|NTERM| 10.4 exp4
 # 6  example_0test0|EMM1.11|NTERM| 10.3 exp6
 # 7 example_0test0|EMM1.123|NTERM| 10.3 exp7
```

- `EMM1(\\.\\d{1,})`: capture group EMM1 with dot and digits

Comment: Again this kind of works, and does using the example given, but as stated in the question  I have a list of 19 "EMM's" to filter by (as  shown in "pat") and don't want to be typing them all out every time?